# Can You Define And Execute A Lambda Method In a Single Statement?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to define and execute a Lambda in one line of code, returning the result of the lambda to a variable?

I want to achieve something like (obviously I am simplifying)

```
int x = 1;
int y = 3; 
int z = (x, y) => { 
    int z = 5;
    return x + y + z;
}
```

In this case, z would be initialized to 9.

Comment: You do not have a named function. So it's unclear what your question is.

Comment: What does this buy you that `z = x + y + 5` doesn't?

Comment: If you're downvoting valid answers, please provide a valid reason

Comment: @RobertHarvey Me and you must have different perception of what a named method means.

Comment: the processing inside the {} of the function will be fairly complex and not related to integers. I am assigning an object's string property a fairly complex calculation of it at runtime.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Your answer declared `Func<int, int, int> func =` ... How is that *not* a named function?

Comment: @RobertHarvey as stated in the question, the specifics have been simplified.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A named method includes an actual declaration of a `public int F(int x, int y)`. I thought he was after declaring a delegate, and didn't know how. Perhaps [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98dc08ac.aspx) would explain.

Comment: @DavidArno: His code causes a compile error.

Comment: @Rok, what benefit do you feel that using an unnamed function (which is what you have shown us, thus answering your own question) would give you over a named function?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought I asked.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Well, your answer might actually work, but it's terrible advice, given that simple mathematical substitution will also work.

Comment: Cannot see the problem all those down voters have. His question clearly asks if it is possible to define and use a lambda on the right hand side without assigning the lambda to a variable first. Since when is not liking the question a reason to down vote? If you don't like that C# is not supporting that feature, down vote C# or whatever but not the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How is that terrible advice? Perhaps the question is unclear and vague as to what he actually needs, but it's definitely an answer that will work in terms of what the OP asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess you're still missing the part of the question that clearly states: **"obviously I am simplifying"**.  Pretty sure someone with 500+ rep wouldn't be asking about how to simply x+y+5!

Comment: @BitTickler, Hmm, you could be right. The question is poorly phrased, but that could indeed be what he's asking.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Your answer doesn't work; Visual Studio complains that x and y in the lambda expression are already being used as local variables.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Edited the answer. I'll leave it deleted anyway.

Comment: What is the name of your method in your world? Is it the z? It´s not the method´s name, it´s only a name of a reference to your returned value `9`. You could of course ommit the assignement to a variable, but thus you´d also ommit the retunred value, so please explain what you mean by "the method´s name"

Comment: Even though I think the question could be phrased differently and better, I really wished it would be removed from hold status as I just happen to have the answer in my clipboard right now, ready for the paste!....*grumble*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Func` to define a callable function, then if you'll only use it in one place:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 3;
int z = (new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) =>
 {
     int c = 5;
     return a + b + c;
 }))(x, y);
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I wanted to achieve, thanks! I guess multiline lambda expressions are not supported just like they're not in Python.

Comment: It's a bit neater if you declare the func as a variable, but not the nicest way to declare inline anonymous functions.

Comment: You can also do it without ``new Func(...)``. Only a pity I cannot add that solution as question is on hold.

Comment: @BitTickler: I'd love to see your simplified version of the code!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you try to use lambdas without assigning the lambda expression to a variable before using in. That is well possible, albeit you will need the respective delegate declarations and a cast to make it happen.

The code below shows how to get there in 5 steps, the last of them probably showing what you try to achieve.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    delegate int F(int x, int y, int z);
    delegate int Fz(int x, int y);
    delegate Fz Cz(F formula, int z);
    class Program
    {
        static Fz Curry(F f, int z)
        {
            return (x, y) => { return f(x,y,z); };
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {   // Verbose version
                F f = (x, y, z) => { return x + y + z; };
                Fz z5 = Curry(f, 5);
                int result = z5(1, 3);
                System.Console.WriteLine("1 + 3 + 5 = {0}", result);
            }
            {   // Inline version 1
                Fz z5 = Curry((x, y, z) => { return x + y + z; }, 5);
                int result = z5(1, 3);
                System.Console.WriteLine("1 + 3 + 5 = {0}", result);
            }
            {   // Inline version 2
                int result = Curry((x, y, z) => { return x + y + z; }, 5)(1, 3);
                System.Console.WriteLine("1 + 3 + 5 = {0}", result);
            }
            {   // Inline version 3
                Cz zn = (f, z) => { return (x, y) => { return f(x, y, z); }; };
                int result = zn((x, y, z) => { return x + y + z; }, 5)(1, 3);
                System.Console.WriteLine("1 + 3 + 5 = {0}", result);
            }
            {   // Inline version 4 (max obfuscation)
                int result = ((Cz)((f, z) => { return (x, y) => { return f(x, y, z); }; }))((x, y, z) => { return x + y + z; }, 5)(1, 3);
                System.Console.WriteLine("1 + 3 + 5 = {0}", result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As another answer pointed out, you can as well use `Func<>` to get the job done. My solution shows that the use of lambdas in C# can be "nearly functional". Only nearly, as the definition of the respective delegates is required and limits the generic nature of what can be done compared to functional languages, such as F#.

The `Func<>` is probably the more concise approach for the problem shown in the question, yet my codes virtue is to outline, that neither `Func<>` nor assignment of a lambda is required. I could not get it to work without the cast `(Cz)`, but do not consider this necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

As your code stands, it will not compile for various reasons:

1. You cannot re-use `x` and `y` in that way.
2. You cannot declare an anonymous function in this way. It must be declared as a delegate before use.

So you'd end up with code like:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 3;
Func<int, int, int> calc = (x1, y1) =>
{
    int z1 = 5;
    return x1 + y1 + z1;
};
var z = calc(x, y);
```

This creates code that is difficult to read though compared with using a named function:

```
...
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 3;
    int z = F(x, y);
}

private static int F(int x, int y)
{
    int z = 5;
    return x + y + z;
};
```

So the answer to your question is "yes", but you are better off not doing so.